# C++ COM : Common mistakes

Tags: c++, com, anti-patterns

I'm having to immerse myself in C++ COM programming again, and have forgotten most of the hard-learned lessons from last time. (when I think the phrase 'never again' may have been used in error.)

What are the most common mistakes and anti-patterns of COM development in C++? I'm using Borland C++Builder, but I'm after things that apply to all C++ compilers.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was not reading the manual. I just tried to get by using tutorials and code samples found online. I wasted many hours on problems that would have been easy to solve had I gotten a good basic understanding of COM.

Comment: This. +1. Definitely. You will drown yourself if you don't master what is going on under the hood. This is sad (and proves that COM is a really poor framework), but hard learned. Make sure you understand the object model, the types, the common interfaces (esp. IDispatch if you are using it).

Answer (score 0):

I'll kick the ball rolling myself with the first one I tripped over again:

Don't pass literal strings to functions that require BSTR parameters. See [the *remarks* section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx).

```
CComPtr<IFoo> foo;

foo->bar("Bletch!"); // No valid BSTR prefix, so bad things will happen.
```

Instead, use...

```
foo->bar(CComBSTR("Bletch!"));
```

Comment: This way BSTR will leak unless the called code takes ownership of it (the latter is very unusual). You should use a wrapper class like `CComBSTR` or `_bstr_t`.

Comment: @sharptooth. Thanks, fixed. I think that's a common mistake, too :-(